# Table cell traversal jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, traversal

I have seen many related posts, but nothing is working for me here. 
So here goes, I am trying to validate data from input on every key press and show error in the next div (in the next cell), tried many traversal combinations but no luck.

Code is given below:-

```
$(this).keypress( function() {
//alert(this);
if (($(this).val().length < 5)||($(this).val().length > 20)) // maybe not working
$(this).parent('td').next('td').children('div').text("Error"); // <- not working
// check input for validity here
});
```

table:-

```
<table width="1032" height="448" align="center" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
   <th width="153" align="right" scope="row"><strong>Name:</strong></th>
    <td width="420">
      <label for="user_name"></label>
     <input name="user_name" type="text" id="user_name" size="70" maxlength="100" value="<?php if (isset($row))  echo $row[1]; ?>"/>

   </td>
   <td width="451"> 
    <div id="div_user_name"></div>
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: There we go! Check my latest edit with the jsfiddle example, working good... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$(this)` is in fact selecting your `input` element, you'll also need to adjust the `if` statement to check for the *value* of the input boxes' length, not the length of the selector:

```
if (($(this).val().length < 5) || ($(this).val().length > 20))
```

Also, I'm assuming you have this selector around your current script code:

```
$("input[type='text']").each(function(){

   $(this).keypress( function() {
   ...
   });

});
```

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t4Ha8/1/) of your code with my input...working...

Comment: is the next line ok? cause when i commented it out it wasnt working either

Comment: thanks a lot, didnt had that selector before, the keypress function :(

Comment: Great stuff, no problem...I hope you understand why it's there and what it's used for! Keep coding! :)